# How to use Any protobuf type in Java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

The code below doesn't work. Is it the best way to use `Any`? I'm trying to read from/write to `Any` and identify the type stored by `Any`.

My `.proto`:

```
  syntax = "proto3";
  import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
  message CommandListPrinters {
  }
  message Commands {
    int32 id = 1;
    repeated google.protobuf.Any command = 2;
  }
```

`my.java`:

```
  CommandListPrinters commandListPrinters = CommandListPrinters.newBuilder().build();
  Any any = Any.newBuilder()
               .setValue(commandListPrinters.toByteString()).build();
  Commands.Builder commandsBuilder = Commands.newBuilder().setId(0);
  commandsBuilder.addCommand(any);
  Commands commands = commandsBuilder.build();
  //
  byte [] ba = commands.toByteArray();      
  Commands cmds2 = Commands.parseFrom(ba);
  for (Any any2 : cmds2.getCommandList()) {
    Descriptor fe = any2.getDescriptorForType();
    // This IF is FALSE;
    if (fe.equals(CommandListPrinters.getDescriptor()) ) {
      CommandListPrinters cmdLR = CommandListPrinters.parseFrom(any2.getValue());
    }
  }
```

Comment: What `Any` are you using?

Comment: If it doesn't work it's clearly not the best way to do things. May I suggest you read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If you want people to help you, you have to make it ***easy*** for them to help. Nobody's going to help if you expect them to read your mind.

Comment: import com.google.protobuf.Any;

Comment: It is a very simple example. Im just trying to create a Any object from my CommandListPrinters object, then readi it back, read a CommandListPrinters object from an Any object.

Comment: I think it is proto 3 already. I have compiled latest protobuf protobuf-java-3.0.0-alpha-4-pre.jar

Comment: I'm sure it's a *very* simple example. You should still provide the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Other SO users should be able, ideally, to copy and paste your code into their IDE, and run it, and see what's wrong. And nobody should have to read the comments to get all the details. Go back and edit your question to reflect your updated information.

Comment: Ok, question looks pretty straight and clear now. dcsohi, could you please help me?

Comment: Actually, I can't. I don't know the first thing about Google Protocol Buffers. :) Your question caught my attention though, and I've just been trying to get you to ask it in such a way that somebody who *does* understand protocol buffers would be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to stackoverflow, so I can't comment, but I was wondering: 
why does your CommandListPrinters message has no fields?

Calling

```
CommandListPrinters.getDescriptor()
```

makes me think CommandListPrinters should have a field descriptor. Also the Any proto doesn't have a field named descriptor_for_type either. See https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/any.proto
So

```
 Descriptor fe = any2.getDescriptorForType();
```

doesn't makes much sense either.

Comment: It's fine that you have a question, but posting this as an answer is not helpful.  It is more than 5 years later, and I am having the same problem with trying to import ```Any```.